# select all columns with multiple text criteria using index search

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

I'm trying to speed up this query:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name != 'John' AND surname != 'Doe' LIMIT 10;
```

The database contains millions of records so it takes very long to do the search using default table scan.

I used this query to index the data:

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON person(name, surname, birthdate, address, gender);
```

However, even after adding this index, I've noticed that it's still very slow. I then ran an `EXPLAIN`

[image: EXPLAIN query]

Why isn't it using the index so that it does an index search instead of a scan?

Comment: A not equals doesn't lend itself to indexes, unlike equality or greater than/less than. It doesn't narrow down the search space enough.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html and https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html might give some insight (especially the WHERE clause analysis section of the second link)

Comment: @Shawn what if I wanted to search for all people with `name` and `surname` not blank `''`? Could I use `length>0` or something else?